# Checking and controlling number of application's threads that actually run in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

Let's say I have Java application that spawns and starts N threads. I run it on Linux or Windows machine with 4 cores. I would assume, that if my app creates bunch of threads, at any time 4 of them (or more if cores use hyper-threading?) are being executed at the same time.

1. Is there some way to check/verify it? I know in Java you can print `Runtime.getRuntime().getAvailableProcesses()`, but does this number always mean number of my threads that would run in parallel? Should I be rather looking into some OS settings?
2. Is it possible, that parallelism would be capped by OS or some JVM settings? (like saying that even though you could run X tasks at once, your app would be restricted to have only X/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `Windows TaskManager`, for example (other OSes will have similar tools). It answers both: you can tell it to show the CPU load for each individual core so you will see how much runs in parallel. And you can right-click on a process and tell the OS to restrict the core usage for that process. Note that on my machine using Windows 7 and Java 7u40 the method `Runtime.availableProcessors()` immediately reflected the changed number of processors when I changed them using the TaskManager.

But even if a process is allowed to use all cores (the default) it might use less if another process is using one or more cores at the same time. That’s multi-tasking. There is no solution to it as every attempt to get the real number of available cores at a time will be rendered obsolete by the fact that that number can change right the next nanosecond.

There is no need to over-complicate your software. If you use the number of threads that matches the number of cores (a few more don’t hurt) as reported by `Runtime.availableProcessors()`, you have done the best to support using all cores. If your application can’t use all cores then, it doesn’t matter as the overhead of a few more threads is negligible. We are not talking about thousands of threads…

Only using too little might leave resources unused.